# Tooltips on a image map?

Tags: image, tooltip, imagemap

I need some help with tooltips and image map..

I want to be able to make "hotspots" on a image when hovering those "hotspots" it will show a tooltip with information..

My code:

```
        <p><img src="../Plan_edited.png" width="2192" height="1520" usemap="#Map">
        <map name="Map">
        <area shape="rect" coords="335,585,480,679" href="#">
        <area shape="rect" coords="483,586,621,679" href="#">
        <area shape="rect" coords="210,733,337,831" href="#">
        <area shape="rect" coords="340,734,452,831" href="#">
        <area shape="rect" coords="455,733,569,830" href="#">
        </map>
        </p>
```

I want the tooltip displayed above the "hotspot" and custom styled like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tooltip_css&stacked=h

Can any one show me, how this is done with maps? All my attempts have failed and can't find clear instructions on how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Okay I finally manged to get some tooltips showing using Tooltipster. But I have some problems with it showing scroll bar and changing the theme I can't figuere out how to do.. Her is my code https://pastebin.com/4RKXcXEt

Comment: And here is a screenshot of the problem: https://imgur.com/a/rw0C4